# Drupal 9 view for webform field summaries

Tags: webforms, drupal-views, drupal-9, drupal-views-relationship

I'm trying to build a view for webform results by field for all submissions, rather than by submission number.

I think I'm missing a relationship or contextual filter but have not been able to figure out how to do this, if it's possible. I attached an image of one field that represents what I'm trying to output: "What is your primary profession/discipline" is the field label, and each of the answers represents one of the options in a select list. The count is represents how many times each option has been chosen. Does anyone have any suggestions for how to start? [a field label with options showing the number of times each option has been submitted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wkRs.png)

I'm using the webform views integration module and have tried creating the view from scratch and duplicating the view that comes with the module. I'm so far only able to output an individual row for each submission, showing values for each submission. I need to show the details by field instead.